# .bash_history and .cache

Tags: bash, files, mercurial

I have a user who's home directory is a Mercurial repository.

Mercurial notified me that there were 2 new unversioned files in my repository. `.bash_history` and `.cache/motd.legal-displayed`.

I assume bash_history is the history of bash commands for my user. I have no idea what the other is.

I don't want these files to be versioned by Mercurial, are they safe to just delete, or will they come back, or mess something up? Can they be moved to somewhere else? Or do I have to add them to my .hgignore file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be a problem to use a directory inside the home as Mercurial repo, and not the home directory itself? I just ask this, since it's a bit unfortunate: like bash creates .bash_history, some commands can have there config files written into the home, so you have to fight with those as well, whenever you use some commands/utils of these kind.

Comment: Not sure, the reason why this is, is because it is a website, and the website is under version control, and the users home directory is set to this for FTP.

Comment: I see, the question if you want/can modify FTP to access that separated directory inside the user's home as the "ftp root" (and/or the website too?), I think it's a more clean solution to start with the basis, than using workarounds like putting .bash_history in .hgignore or so. As an internet system engineer since 10 years, I can tell that every time I want only a workaround (and not rethinking the concept) will make me pay later quite badly ... Anyway for sure you can do whatever you want, I only wanted to share my own experiences and opinion about the topic now.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and is really why I posted this question rather than just adding them to .hgignore, can you point me someone that explains how to make the users home directory, and the users ftp root, separate? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of ftp server are you using?

Comment: @LGB I am using `vsftpd`

Comment: I haven't ever used vsftpd. It would be the best to set up a virtual user (as far as I know it supports that) with the home directory set to the directory inside the "real UNIX user", which holds your repo. Then you can have even different username/passwd for that FTP, and also for the UNIX shell access (login, via ssh, or whatever). I like this solution more, then you have separated control over the FTP "part" and the shell level access.